# How do I check that all MPI procs were used to call a procedure?

Tags: mpi

I have designed a procedure that must be called by all processors in the communicator in order to function properly.  If the user called it with only the root rank, I want the procedure to know this and then produce a meaningful error message to the user of the procedure.  At first I thought of having the procedure call a checking routine shown below:

```
subroutine AllProcsPresent
  ! Checks that all procs have been used to call this procedure
  use MPI_stub, only: nproc, Allreduce
  integer :: counter
  counter=1
  call Allreduce(counter) ! This is a stub procedure that will add "counter" across all procs
  if (counter(1)==get_nproc()) then 
     return
  else 
     print *, "meaningful error"
  end if
end subroutine AllProcsPresent
```

But this won't work because the Allreduce is going to wait for all procs to check in and if only root was used to do the call, the other procs will never arrive.  Is there a way to do what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

There's not much you can do here.  You might want to look at 'collecheck' for ideas, but it's hard to find a good resource for that package.  Here's its git home:

http://git.mpich.org/mpe.git/tree/HEAD:/src/collchk

If you look at 'NOTES' there's an item about "call consistency" described as "Ensures that all processes in the communicator have made the same call in a given event".   Hope that can give you some ideas.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I didn't really want to have to pull in another package.  I'll have to take a look at it.

Comment: of course.  My initial reaction was that what you are asking is impossible, but then I remembered collcheck did something similar.    I don't even know if it still compiles nowadays, but it might demonstrate approaches you can take in your own code.

Answer (score 0):

Ensuring that a collective operation is entered by all ranks within a communicator is the responsibility of the programmer.

However, you might consider using the MPI 3.0 non-blocking collective `MPI_Ibarrier` with an `MPI_Test` loop and time out. However, non-blocking collectives can't be cancelled, so if the other ranks do not join in the operation within your time out, you will have to abort the entire job. Something like:

```
void AllPresent(MPI_Comm comm, double timeout) {
  int all_here = 0;
  MPI_Request req;
  MPI_Ibarrier(comm, &req);
  double start_time = MPI_Wtime();
  do {
    MPI_Test(&req, &all_here, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
    sleep(0.01);
    double now = MPI_Wtime();
    if (now - start_time > timeout) {
      /* Print an error message */
      MPI_Abort(comm, 1);
    }
  } while (!all_here);
  /* Run your procedure now */
}
```